# Not able to upload and show the image properly in android studio

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio

I am trying to create an interface to upload image from sd card and print it on my android screen using this [tutorial](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-android-image-picker/).

However, when I upload the image from my app, it does not get uploaded and printed on my screen. I have the image in /sdcard/image.jpg but when I check the path of the image in my code, it gives /document/image:11. The bitmap is null. Can anyone help to find the error in the code and correct it?

Here is my code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

            return;
        }

        Bitmap bitmap   = null;
        String path     = "";

        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            path = getRealPathFromURI(mImageCaptureUri); //from Gallery

            if (path == null)
                path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath(); //from File Manager

            if (path != null)
                bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        } else {
            path    = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();
            bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        }
        if(bitmap==null) Toast.makeText(this, path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("SOMETHING", path);

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
```

Here is my logcat:

```
02-18 20:03:51.430 25924-25924/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-18 20:03:51.580 25924-25939/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
02-18 20:03:51.810 25924-25931/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
02-18 20:03:52.060 25924-25924/? D/Atlas: Validating map...
02-18 20:03:52.170 25924-25939/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-18 20:03:52.730 25924-25939/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7ffb1ffdff00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
I/Choreographer: Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 82 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7ffb178eb580, error=EGL_SUCCESS
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:11: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/CursorWrapperInner: Cursor finalized without prior close()
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7ffb179dd940, error=EGL_SUCCESS
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7ffb1ffdff00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7ffb178eb5c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7ffb178ebcc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:11: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7ffb179dd940, error=EGL_SUCCESS
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7ffb1fcd3680, error=EGL_SUCCESS
I/Choreographer: Skipped 310 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a mistake in that tutorial.

When defining the intent for sd card, replace

`intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);`

with

`intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);`